# CloudBees SDK installation error : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cloudbees.sdk.Bees

Tags: cloudbees

I was trying to install the CloudBees SDK in Linux but keep getting the same error while trying to execute the "bees" command on my terminal.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.cloudbees.sdk.boot.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:64)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cloudbees.sdk.Bees
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.cloudbees.sdk.boot2.BeesLoader.run(BeesLoader.java:151)
    at com.cloudbees.sdk.boot2.BeesLoader.main(BeesLoader.java:62)
    ... 5 more
```

I already double checked the `$BEES_HOME` environment variable and it's set correctly (full path to the directory). I also deleted the .bees directory in my `$HOME` but none of those action helped me to fix the issue.

I followed the exact same instructions from here: 
https://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/BeesSDK

My setup info:

- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
- Fedora 18
- CloudBees SDK 1.5.0

Answer (score 0):

I just set it up on a new Arch Linux box with java 7 (same version, from oracle) - and it was ok.

Is JAVA_HOME set as well? (shouldn't strictly be needed)